# GetListItems times out when I include a query

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint

I'm trying to call `Lists.GetListItems` with a CAML query.  It works fine when I don't include a query parameter, but I get a time-out error when I include the query.  Assuming that my web service is called `TestWebService`, code is:

```
    public static void GetListItemsTest()
    {
        try
        {
            string listName = "TestList";
            string[] fields = { "ID", "Title" };
            string queryStr =
                       "<GroupBy collapse='true'>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='" + fields[1] + "' />" +
                       "</GroupBy>" +
                       "<OrderBy>" +
                          "<FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='False' />" +
                       "</OrderBy>";
            XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
            XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
            query.InnerXml = queryStr;
            viewFields.InnerXml = "";
            TestWebService.Lists lists = new TestWebService.Lists();
            lists.Url = "http://wss/sites/TestWebService/_vti_bin/lists.asmx";
            lists.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            XmlNode responseNode = lists.GetListItems(listName, null, query, viewFields, "1000000", null, null);
            Console.WriteLine("ran successfully");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
```

The call to `GetListItems` hangs, then throws a WebException with the message "The operation has timed out."  If I change the `query.InnerXml` assignment to:

```
query.InnerXml="";
```

then `GetListItems` successfully returns a value for `responseNode`.  So it must have something to do with the CAML query fragment.

On further investigation, I found that the `GroupBy` element is the source of the problem; with the `OrderBy` element commented out, the query times out, and with the `GroupBy` element commented out, the query succeeds.  I'm wondering if `GroupBy` can't handle large data sets, or it handles them too slowly; this set has about 20,000 elements, with generally not more than 5 or 6 duplicates of each Title value.  Would LINQ be more applicable in this situation?  Or is there a way to do this with straight CAML?

Answer (score 1):

With 20,000 items on a SharePoint 2010 system you might risk getting an *SPQueryThrottledException*. A typical user is limited to 5000, and a few privileged users to 20,000 items returned by a query.

Have you set up an index on the Title column? This might improve performance on the GroupBy. Otherwise I suspect that the query forces the retrieval of all items, and then groups them. Try grouping them, and retrieving them in pages, rather than all at once.

I don't know it it's entirely relevant, but I did just blog about queries on [large lists](http://www.novolocus.com/2012/07/11/dealing-with-large-lists-part-2-coping-with-large-queries/).

Comment: The list is hosted on SP2007, if that matters.  Retrieving the items in pages is very time-consuming, at the rate of ~100 items per page.  For now I'm going to try getting the whole list without grouping, then group and sort it using LINQ.